# Client Side People Picker Error: RemoveCssClassFromElement!

Tags: people-picker

First of all, this is my first time ever asking anything here so please be gentle.

I am developing this custom html.page(SharePoint Hosted App) for editing purposes of specific SharePoint lists.
I have a client side people picker on the page (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/jj713593%28v=office.15%29.aspx) and everything is working fine until the following:

After getting the wanted User from the people picker and selecting it, i get the following Error:

> "0x800a1391 - JavaScript runtime error: 'RemoveCssClassFromElement' is undefined".

The error happens in the `_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js` reference file, but i have no idea where it tries to to get that `RemoveCssClassFromElement()` function.

Everything works perfectly if i run the code in default.aspx, but when in custom.html it doesn't

Any ideas?

Scripts i am using in my Custom.html (in order):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/lib/jquery-1.9.1.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/4.0/1/MicrosoftAjax.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.3/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/SP.init.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.runtime.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/sp.core.js"></script>


<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/lib/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/lib/angular-route.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/src/services.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/src/controllers.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/src/App.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/init.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/1033/strings.js"></script>">
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/clienttemplates.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/clientforms.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/clientpeoplepicker.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/autofill.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../Scripts/PeoplePicker.js"></script>
```

UPDATE! picker control:

```
<div id="peoplePickerDiv"></div>
<div>
    <br/>
    <input type="button" value="Get User Info" onclick="getUserInfo()"></input>
    <br/>
    <h1>User info:</h1>
    <p id="resolvedUsers"></p>
    <h1>User keys:</h1>
    <p id="userKeys"></p> 
    <h1>User ID:</h1>
    <p id="userId"></p>
</div>
```

Custom.js is as it is on the MSDN link!

Comment: Can you please update the question with `Custom.html` file content (atleast the markup of the picker control)

Comment: Added the picker control

Comment: Please specify where the page is hosted. Are you building a SharePoint App? If that's the case, is it SharePoint-hosted or provider-hosted?

Comment: Yea sry forgot a lot of info it seems. It is part of a SharePoint Hosted App!

Answer (score 0):

The function "RemoveCssClassFromElement" is defined in core.js file. Just add reference to it in html markup.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="/_layouts/15/core.js"></script>
```